# JMock static Mockery vs. local Mockery

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmock

We have a large number of unit tests written using JMock 2.5.1 and most (all?) of them use local Mockery object such as:

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class SomeTestClass {

    private Mockery context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        context = new Mockery();
    }
}
```

We decided to upgrade to JMock 2.8.3 so that we could use new features, such as thread safe mocks.  However, with the existing unit tests running under 2.8.3, I get:

```
Testcase: testReordering_GoingUp(com.hcs.orc.board.NameTagList2Test):   Caused an ERROR
Mockery named 'context' is null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockery named 'context' is null
    at org.jmock.integration.junit4.JMock.mockeryOf(JMock.java:67)
    at org.jmock.integration.junit4.JMock.createTest(JMock.java:35)
```

It seems that JMock 2.8.3 requires a static version of the Mockery.  That is:

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class SomeTestClass {

    public static Mockery context;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void globalSetUp() {
        context = new Mockery();
    }
}
```

However, this creates bleed over in the Mockery between tests.  That is the previously created mock objects still exist even after the test resulting in errors such as:

```
a mock with name fullScreenFrame already exists
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a mock with name fullScreenFrame already exists
    at org.jmock.Mockery.mock(Mockery.java:128)
    at org.jmock.Mockery.mock(Mockery.java:120)
```

Is there a way to upgrade from JMock 2.5.1 to JMock 2.8.3 without reworking 100s (1000s?) of unit tests?

**NOTE:** Edited to reflect moving to JMock 2.8.3. JMock 2.6.1 is not the latest code, despite what jmock.org's very out of date and unmaintained website says.

Comment: Posted a different version of this question to JMock here: https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/issues/103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I settled on, was between my first pass and @Foxsly's answer.  It allows me to move to JMock 2.8.3 without rewritting more than my declaration of the Mockery (and remove the `@RunWith`).

```
public class SomeTestClass {

   @Rule
   public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

   private SomeOtherClass fullScreenFrame;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       fullScreenFrame = context.mock(SomeOtherClass.class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `@RunWith(JMock.class)` annotation - I believe it was deprecated with one of the 2.6.x releases (whichever introduced the JUnitRuleMockery).

Adding on to that, you can use annotations to instantiate your mocks if you'd like:

```
public class SomeTestClass {
    @Rule
    public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

    @Mock private SomeOtherClass mockedDependency;

}
```

Comment: I ended up using the Rule, like you suggested, but it wasn't necessary to use the Mock, which would have required rewritting 1000s of lines that declare mocks.  Fortunately, the Mock wasn't necessary.

Comment: Makes sense - I was just providing the annotation-based Mock as an option, you can certainly do what you did below and use the traditional mocking.

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to work around the problem by creating the Mockery in the Test classes constructor.  Then it is exists with JMock looks for it, but it will be refreshed for each test run.

Possible work around:

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class SomeTestClass {

    private Mockery context;

    public SomeTestClass() {
         context = new Mockery();
    }
}
```